# Is unmodified thinset ok for radiant heating under hardwood flooring?

Tags: hardwood-floor, radiant-heating, thinset

So me and my dad are renovating and decided to add electric radiant heating in out living room/kitchen. We are following this video as a guide https://youtu.be/sXhT1fYVPps. They said to use latex modified thinset above the wires. My dad bought unmodified thinset by accident. We were wondering if it was alright to use the unmodified stuff. If it is not a good idea to use unmodified thinset, what would be a good brand of latex modified thinset to use because they don't recommend one in the video.

The help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add the modifier to the thin set and reduce the amount of water, with radiant heat you do want the additional strength that add mix provides I used to use a brand called moo’s milk. But I think most addmix modifiers are about the same. I use addmix in my thinset and in the grout, it really is not much of a additional cost and provides superior strength. The addmix works just as well as purchasing modified thinset.